# HTML Select Box Will Not Change Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box that is dynamically populated with options pulled from a database. After it is populated with all available options the current selected option is then supposed to be populated. The problem is, the select box will not actually set the value like the code is telling it to.

Here's what I have:

```
//Calling the function to populate the lots
vehicles.populateLots('selVOLot');

//Getting the Vehicle Owner data
var vehicleOwner = functions.getVehicleOwnerSearchResults(vehicleID, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', peopleID, academicYear, '', '', '', 0);

console.log('lot = ' + vehicleOwner[0].ParkingTag);
$('#selVOLot').val(vehicleOwner[0].ParkingTag);
```

Here's the function used to populate the options:

```
//Function used to populate the Lots select box(s)
vehicles.populateLots = function (ID) {
  console.log('populating lots = ' + ID);
  //Getting the Lots
  var lots = functions.getLots();

  //Emptying the existing lot
  $('#' + ID).empty();

  //Setting it to a variable
  voLot = document.getElementById(ID);
  if (ID == 'selVSLot') {
      voLot.options[voLot.options.length] = new Option('All', '');
      voLot.options[voLot.options.length] = new Option('No Lot', 'NO');
  } else {
      voLot.options[voLot.options.length] = new Option('', '');
  }

  //Populating the lot select options
  for (var h = 0; h < lots.length; h++) {
      voLot.options[voLot.options.length] = new Option(lots[h].LotCode, 
  lots[h].LotCode);
  }
}
```

So to walk it through step by step:

1. We call vehicles.populateLots and send the ID of the select box to populate the available options.
2. We call functions.getVehicleOwnerSearchResults to gather the corresponding data that we want to populate.
3. We then populate said data.

Step 3 is where the problem is. The code seems to be ignoring the line `$('#selVOLot').val(vehicleOwner[0].ParkingTag);`. I even wrote the value to the console to make sure it's actually bringing back a value. The console value is correct. I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.

**EDIT**
I'm not sure how to link a name up here, Pointy, but yes, it is populating correctly. Here's a screenshot of the HTML via console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txa7I.jpg

**EDIT #2**

So this is getting stranger by the minute. Apparently, if the value is less than 3 characters it will not populate. If I find someone who has the value of COM it loads just fine. But if I find someone who has the value of B it won't populate.

Comment: And you've verified that one of the `<option>` elements has that "tag" value is the value of its "value" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went to look at the database and found the problem. There's a space after the value.